# How do I make display:none to display:block elements not take up its original space in DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have this sample snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/uyg8tauo/ wherein several `div`s are initially defined as `display: none;` and upon clicking the buttons, I would like them to appear by changing the `display` property of the element to `block`.

However, I would like the elements to cascade properly based on the buttons I actually clicked. For instance, if I click the the first button 4 times, the elements with `id`s `"school_" + n` show up one after another and if I click on the second button the `div` with `id` `"noSchool_" + n` appears **after** the first ones not on where it is exactly written on my DOM.

Please take note that it has to be supported by legacy browsers (IE8<). Apparently, my `div`s have to pre-defined and cannot be dynamically added. I really hope I made myself clear with my problem and any feasible solution is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: If you can't modify the DOM, I guess your 2nd option would be to use a flexbox layout where you can specify order using css.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about your restrictions? Can't modify the DOM? Can't use jQuery?

Comment: Add it to your question then, and be precise about which browsers you need to support

Comment: Why don't you generate the `DOM/HTML` in the runtime?

Comment: But if you are allowed to modify the dom, you can simply just append the div once again and it would end up last in the DOM.

Comment: @jishi How do I do that if my divs are pre-defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you re-append a DOM element into it's same container, it will be put last in the DOM tree. Consider the following:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="button-1">1</div>
  <div id="button-2">2</div>
  <div id="button-3">3</div>
</div>
```

Now, if you would do this:
`document.getElementById('container').appendChild(document.getElementById('button-1'));`

This would effectively switch the DOM into the following structure:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="button-2">2</div>
  <div id="button-3">3</div>
  <div id="button-1">1</div>
</div>
```

As explained in the first paragraph here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: I'm trying to do this approach, but with jQuery so I can eliminate the document.getElementById s. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Setting the display to block after appending does the trick! Thank you again.